# Which is the meaning of ":>" in sh script?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have seen the following string in a sh script:

```
:> /tmp/foo
```

Is there a difference between this string and the following string?

```
> /tmp/foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` is a no-op shell builtin, always returning a success exit status without outputting anything. It is a synonym of the `true` builtin, but shorter.

The two are equivalent, although the first suggests that the `:` might be a placeholder for something in the future.